# Winforms DataGridView фильтрация по дате

Tags: winforms, datetime

Пытаюсь сделать фильтрацию по месяцу в DataGridView. Так выглядит окно приложения:[image: окно приложения]

Пробовал разные варианты, и при этом получал очень странные результаты:

  1.

```js
string filter = "";
bool first = true;
if (checkBox1.Enabled) {
  if (first) {
    DateTime date_st = new DateTime(filterMounth.Value.Year, filterMounth.Value.Month, 1);
    DateTime date_end = date_st.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
    filter = $ "PaymentMonth >= #{date_st.ToShortDateString()}# and PaymentMonth <= #{date_end.ToShortDateString()}#";
  }
  MessageBox.Show(filter);
  paymentBindingSource.Filter = filter;
}
```

Строка фильтра при этом содержит:
**PaymentMonth >= #01.11.2019# and PaymentMonth <= #30.11.2019#**
И выдает ошибку - "Строка не распознана как действительное значение DateTime.

2. Убрал AddDays(-1) у даты конца месяца и изменил в условии <= на < (т.е. дата должна быть меньше 1 числа след. месяца) и ошибки нет, но при этом он работает не правильно(Или не так как я предпологал?). А именно: дата попадающая в диапазон (19.11.2019) отсеивается фильтром.

Comment: Ему не нравится именно дата окончания. Даже если вводить ручками он все равно ругается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заменил # на ' в фильтре и все заработало.